# Ubuntu 14.10 slow

Tags: unity, 32-bit, 14.10

I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my Dell Latitude D600. It has the Pentium M CPU so, I had to forcepae in order for it to install. Now that it's installed I'm noticing the ui is extremely slow. When a window fades out it refreshes once every 2 seconds or so. It seems the computer itself is pretty fast, just the window animations seem to make it unbearably slow. Is there anything I may be doing wrong? I think it may be a video card driver issue but, I don't know how to find the driver and install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu's default desktop, Unity, is likely too much for your computer to handle.
If you want to use an [Ubuntu flavor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) that may perform better, I recommend [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/). It has a more lightweight desktop that uses less resources. Hopefully you have upgraded the amount of RAM in your Latitude; [a quick search](http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-latitude-d600/specs/) shows that it came with 128MB, which is too low, even for Lubuntu.

If Lubuntu does not perform well, then you should try some other distros. [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/) is a good resource for discovering new distros. A few I would look into would be Puppy Linux and Dam Small Linux just from my memory.

Comment: Ok, I'm installing that now. Also, yes, I upgraded the ram to 2GB (The maximum it supports)

Comment: I've heard, but can't confirm, that 14.10 does not work good on Intel hardware. You may want to try 14.04 Lubuntu.

Comment: Weird. I'm using 14.10 as my main computer on my brand new computer and it seems to be working fine. I used a 12.04 lubuntu disk to install (because I had it lying around) and I'm going to use the Update Manager to upgrade to 14.04 lubuntu. It also seems the network driver is acting up when I tried to install it with Additional Drivers. I'll try to update it to 14.04 then if it still doesn't work, make another thread.

Comment: 12.04 lts has the 2d desktop which works well on my old hardware, if you don't mind using the non-latest

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problems with the intel chipset.  The problem is, like you initially suspected, the video; specifically the Radeon 9000 chipset with 32MB of memory. If you had the ATi driver installed when you upgraded, it almost assuredly won't work correctly, according to some random forum posters - along with personal experience. The open source Radeon driver should have been fine, though.  According to the link that was posted earlier, you should be OK with the RV250 driver.  You can confirm this with

```
less /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Look for something like (II) LoadModule: "radeon" or "RV250" or "rv250" - something like that.

I'm a little mystified by booting with forcepae - ah, I see that older Pentium M's (Banias) didn't advertise their PAE capability. Newer Pentium M's (Dothan) did advertise their PAE capability.

That [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE) did recommend ToriOS (super light weight distro), [nOS](http://www.nos.net.nz/) (12.04 rolling release distro until 2017), and [Bohdi Linux](http://www.bodhilinux.com/) (also 2017), along with [Xubuntu 12.04](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/).  However, they explicitly don't recommend Lubuntu 12.04 as it is unsupported.